# Using AppleScript to modify settings/system preferences

Tags: applescript

I am trying to make an AppleScript that toggles automatic rearranging of spaces. I am able to get the AppleScript to open system preferences and go into mission control settings, however i am not sure how to check the box which i want to change.

```applescript
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click menu item "Mission Control" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
    delay 2
    tell window "Mission Control"
            //additional code goes here
    end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Is there a way to see what the components of the window are so i know if i need to go into a table, or something else, before i am able to access the check boxes that toggle the settings

Comment: Alex you are plenty of answers. Why didn’t you choose a correct one? Any of them are not good enough? People have spent time to answer your question. It should be fair to choose the answer. Anyway, it’s up to you.

Comment: Alex please, choose an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should to what you want.

In this example `Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use` is the checkbox you want to check.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    delay 2
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.expose"
    delay 2
    tell application "System Events"
        click checkbox "Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use" of group 2 of window "Mission Control" of application process "System Preferences"
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

And this if you wanna check it only if it's not checked:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    delay 2
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.expose"
    delay 2
    tell application "System Events"
        tell checkbox "Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use" of group 2 of window "Mission Control" of application process "System Preferences"
            if (get its value) = 0 then click it
        end tell
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

And if you wanna list all the UIElements in the window:

```
set myArray to {}
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    delay 2
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.expose"
    delay 2
    tell application "System Events"
        tell window "Mission Control" of application process "System Preferences"
            repeat with uiElem in entire contents as list
                set myArray to myArray & ((class of uiElem as string) & " : " & name of uiElem as string)
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: @AlexStedman You are welcome! But... did you forget to flag it as the correct answer? ;)

Comment: You tell in a way like that? `set myvar to ""
tell application [...] tell window "Mission Control" of application process "System Preferences"
   set myvar to get entire contents
  end tell [...]` I could, but it's more messy and confusing. Anyway I preferred to suggest a way to iterate through all elements. And if you like you could go through the hierarchy also with Accessibility Inspector. BTW... to much information for a question that ask only few things and didn't even choice a correct answer ;)

Comment: @CJK I forgot to tag you in my previous comment ;)

Comment: @shadowsheep sorry about that. I'm new to stack exchange and didn't know I was supposed to select the correct answer. Seems obvious now

Answer (score 7):

This is an alternative method using a *shell command* via AppleScript, which has the benefit of not requiring **System Preferences** to be open/running/visible.  It's also much faster.

If you do happen to have it open in order to monitor whether the script below works, bear in mind that the GUI (what you see) is not updated until you close *System Preferences*, and open it up again.

To set *Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use* to true (i.e. so the checkbox is ticked):

```
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.dock 'mru-spaces' -bool true; killall Dock"
```

To set it to false, i.e. untick the checkbox, change `true` to `false` in the line of code above.

To toggle the setting, this short script will achieve that:

```
    set currentSetting to ¬
        (do shell script ¬
            "defaults read com.apple.dock 'mru-spaces'") ¬
            as integer as boolean

    do shell script ¬
        "defaults write com.apple.dock 'mru-spaces' -bool " & ¬
        (not currentSetting) & ¬
        "; killall Dock"
```

**Note:** Tested with MacOS High Sierra, but should work (I believe) in OS X Mavericks and later.

---

#### Other Settings

***When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application***

```
do shell script "defaults write -g AppleSpacesSwitchOnActivate -bool true"
```

(or `false` if you want the option off.)

***Group windows by application***

```
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.dock 'expose-group-apps' -bool true; killall Dock"
```

(or `false` if you want the option off.)

Answer (score 3):

Let me start by saying while both of the other answers prior to this one do work, nonetheless I wouldn't use either one of them for the following reasons.

The answer presented by shadowsheep works however it needlessly exposes the System Preferences GUI and I believe unless your system is really slow the *value* of the `delay` *command* is excessive by 50% and only one should be necessary in this use case.

The answer presented by CJK works however it uses `killall Dock` which is visually distracting and causes all minimized windows on all Desktops to be unminimized leading to further visual distractions, and clutters the Desktop(s), which can then require the User to cleanup the mess. Even without other windows open it's still more so a visual distraction then what I'll present.

Now every User has different work habits so maybe none of the reasons mentioned are of any consequence to you. Personally, I work between four virtual Desktops and can have dozens of windows opened in numerous apps across the Desktops with many, if not most minimized at times. Using `killall Dock` for me is the last thing I want to do most of the time.

With that said, here's an alternative to both of the existing answers prior to this one.

It's probably safe to say that most Users don't open and leave open **System Preferences** however the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* checks to see if it's running and if so closes it. This is so it can be opened without showing the GUI, so as not to have to see the the visual distraction of have the GUI change as the script progresses.

This *example* **AppleScript** *code* simply toggles the state of the target checkbox:

```
if running of application "System Preferences" then
    quit application "System Preferences"
    delay 1
end if
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.expose"
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        tell group 2 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
            click checkbox "Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use"
        end tell
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

This *example* **AppleScript** *code* conditionally clicks the target checkbox using `0` or `1` in
 `if value is equal to 0 then click it`. Use `0` to only click it if it's not checked and `1` to only click it if it's checked.

```
if running of application "System Preferences" then
    quit application "System Preferences"
    delay 1
end if
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.expose"
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        tell group 2 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
            tell checkbox "Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use"
                if value is equal to 0 then click it
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

Both *example* **AppleScript** *code* blocks shown work fast and without seeing the **System Preferences** GUI and the only visual effect is the **Dock Tile** for **System Preferences** does a single bounce and may not even be noticeable, especially when compared to the visual distraction of `killall Dock`.

---

Note that the *value* of the `delay` *commands* may need to be adjusted for your system, and or additional `delay` *commands* may or may not be needed. Adjust *values* of and or add/remove the `delay` *commands* as appropriate.

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any other *error handling* then what's shown and is meant only to show one of many ways accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

Comment: @CJK, you said, "Actually, one of the settings in my answer doesn't require a killall Dock", well the primary focus of the OP is to toggle the checkbox for "Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use" and the portion of your answer for this uses and requires `killall Dock`, the fact that the `defaults read` command neither needs nor uses it or the Other Settings commands that actually have nothing to do with the question asked don't use it are totally irrelevant to the primary points I've made for posting the answer I did. Continued in next comment...

Comment: As to "I'm left wondering whether I missed something in reading this answer. Unless I missed some deeper insight, it seems like your answer is a clone of the one by @shadowsheep, except that you removed the activate commands", yes you are indeed missed something and while my answer uses similar code, and many answer often do, it is distinctly different and while it does the same setting it does so in quite a different manner and IMO is the proper way do do it, as it does it faster then shadowsheep's and without the visual distractions caused by both the other answers!

Comment: Excellent Behavior! Thanks. It is 1000x more elegant than killall Dock or a Visual Click