# Using Applescript to change System Preferences

Tags: applescript

So I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49214368/) and this mostly solves my problem, but I want to do more than just a checkbox, for my option, which is to enable mouse keys, you need to also navigate submenus and stuff. I've come so far:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
     activate
     delay 2
     set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
     delay 2
     #More Code here to select submenu "Pointer Controls", "Alternative Control Methods" and click the checkbox "Enable Mouse Keys"
end tell
```

If you're asking why I didn't just enable the option to enable mouse keys with 5 clicks of the option button with

```
 tell application "System Events"
      repeat 5
           key code 58 #key code for the option key
           delay 0.05
      end repeat
 end tell
```

I tried that, it just wouldn't work.

Comment: As you did not include which version of **macOS** you are using and what the other _settings_ your are trying to change, I posted some _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ that when uncommented appropriately works for me in **macOS Catalina** and it may need some changes for other versions of **macOS**. That is the nature of **UI Scripting**, in that it can be kludgy and the _hierarchical UI element structure_ is subject to change in different version of **macOS**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

Note that various *events* are commented out so you can uncomment those which you want.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
--  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "Alternate_Pointer_Actions" of ¬
        pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
    activate -- # Is needed because of 'sheet 1'.
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        tell window 1
            
            set i to 0
            repeat until (exists checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of group 1)
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
            
            tell tab group 1 of group 1
                -- if (value of checkbox 1 as boolean) then click checkbox 1 -- # "Enable Mouse Keys"
                -- if not (value of checkbox 1 as boolean) then click checkbox 1 -- # "Enable Mouse Keys"
                -- click checkbox 1 --  # "Enable Mouse Keys"
                -- click button 1 --    # "Options…"
            end tell
            
            set i to 0
            repeat until (exists sheet 1)
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
            
            tell sheet 1
            
                --  # [] Ignore built-in trackpad when Mouse Keys is on
                -- if (value of checkbox 1 as boolean) then click checkbox 1
                -- if not (value of checkbox 1 as boolean) then click checkbox 1
                -- click checkbox 1

                --  # [] Press the Option key five times to toggle Mouse Keys
                if (value of attribute "AXEnabled" of checkbox 2) then
                    -- if (value of checkbox 2 as boolean) then click checkbox 2
                    -- if not (value of checkbox 2 as boolean) then click checkbox 2
                    -- click checkbox 2
                end if
                
                --  # Initial Delay:
                -- set value of slider 1 to 3 --    # Valid values, as a whole number: 0 thru 4
                
                --  # Maximum Speed:
                -- set value of slider 2 to 6 --    # Valid values, as a whole number: 0 thru 10
                
                -- click button 1 --    # "OK"
                -- click button 2 --    # "Cancle"
                
            end tell
            
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

---

**Notes:**

In the `tell sheet 1` *block*, it's coded with **[] Ignore built-in trackpad when Mouse Keys is on** *checkbox* first as checking it also checkes the **[] Press the Option key five times to toggle Mouse Keys** *checkbox* and disables it. You may also need to add some additional *logic* depending on how exactly you are trying to toggle the *state* of these these *checkboxes*.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: thanks a lot, I am running MacOS Big Sur 11.4 Beta, and it seems to be running fine, except that it doesn't actually click the box that enables mouse keys, is that a problem in your script or in my OS? Also, it doesn't actually quit System Preferences after.

Comment: @gurkensaas, First I want to say that **Apple** has changed something with **System Events** in that it will report **error "Application isn’t running." number -600 from application "System Events"** with some _code_ that works flawlessly in **macOS Catalina** but in the case where the _hierarchical UI element structure_ in **macOS Big Sur** is exactly the same it can error the first time the _script_ is run. Still working on tracking down exactly what cause the issue, however a workaround using a `tell application "System Events" to activate` and a `delay 0.5` seems to workaround the issue.

Comment: @gurkensaas, That said... As I previous stated in a comment "I posted some _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ that when uncommented appropriately works for me in **macOS Catalina** and it may need some changes for other versions of **macOS.**" What I forgot to say is... It may also need some changes if you do not have a **built-in trackpad**, which in that case for the **[] Press the Option key five times to toggle Mouse Keys** _checkbox_ it becomes `checkbox 1`. Most importantly, you have to uncomment the appropriate lines of _code_ based on what it is you want to have happen, for it to happen.

Comment: I just forgot to uncomment the code, I'm so terribly sorry for wasting your time, the script works flawlessly.